# Redirection to 404 page for BAD / FAKE pages not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, redirect

***Note - Site does direct to https for SSL cert**

Ok this is on a live site so I'll be able to give links to test.

So if you access my site https://thebigmmorpglist.com and put in a random fake page such as https://thebigmmorpglist.com/nosuchpage.php it will keep the url as https://thebigmmorpglist.com/nosuchpage.php but have the looks of the home page with a messed up stylesheet.  Also say you go to https://thebigmmorpglist.com/12-sky-2/nosuchpage.php it will also show the home page while keeping the url as https://thebigmmorpglist.com/12-sky-2/nosuchpage.php but have NO STYLESHEET AT ALL (Probably because its in a different directory.  I am so confused on how to fix this, I believe I have the redirects correct in my .htaccess file.

(Sorry if I am wording / describing anything wrong)

Ive already tried changing the location of my error page and changing around the order / layout of my redirect code.  I am at a complete loss as to hwo I can correct this and I cannot find anything on Stack Overflow that replicates my issue.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} thebigmmorpglist\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thebigmmorpglist.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I am hoping for the fake page to redirect to error.php that is located in my root directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I was dumb and duped the redirect for https due to my site no longer being a wordpress site...*

**Had to Remove this code**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Fixed / Working Code:**

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} thebigmmorpglist\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thebigmmorpglist.com/$1 [R,L]
```